# Integration question (u-substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int \limits _0^\pi \sin x\cos^2 x\ dx\,.
$$

Comment: HI @programmer!  Welcome to Math.SE.  We don't mind helping people out here, but you may want to be a bit more specific with questions like this.  For example, what are you having problems with specifically?

Comment: @RonGordon Nevermind! I was just unable to get the correct substitution. Sorry!

Comment: @programmer Just curious, what substitution were you using before?

Comment: @YagnaPatel  I used u = sin(x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$u=\cos(x)\implies du=-\sin(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^\pi \sin{x}\cos^{2}{x}\ \mathrm dx$

Let $u=\cos(x)$ and $\mathrm du=-\sin(x) \mathrm dx$

Thus

$\int_0^\pi \sin{x}\cos^{2}{x}\ \mathrm dx= -\int_{1}^{-1} u^{2} \mathrm du=-\frac{u^3}{3}]_1^{-1}=-\frac{\cos^3x}{3}]_0^{\pi}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Absolutely.  I will downvote anyone who posts a full solution to what is obviously a simple homework problem for which there is zero effort shown.  We are not a homework mill here.

Comment: @RonGordon Hi Ron, my apologies for posting this question. I just recently started integration and I've done a couple of hundred questions in the past few days as well as other topics such as complex numbers and mechanics amongst other things. I must have had a brain freeze, which is why I posted this question, as I have no idea why I was unable to solve a simple question. Sorry about this. Perhaps I should take a small break haha.

Comment: @programmer Asking a simple question is not the issue - after all, there is no universal idea of simple, and what's simple for you is likely very difficult for someone else. The issue is purely one of presentation: You state it with no context, no mention of your knowledge or what you've tried, and with a commanding tone. This is a very poor format, and will have a very negative response.